# Unity3D: changing camera from perspective to orthographic hides UI elements

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, camera, perspective, orthographic

In my project I'm using 2 cameras:

1. the Main Camera for the scene 3D elements;
2. a secondary camera for UI elements, which I need(?*) since I want to render 3D objects inside the UI (I followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yzpjkoE0YA)).

?* - I'm actually not 100% sure if that's the only and/or correct way to render 3D objects in UI, but I haven't found any other solution.

#### Unity Inspector

##### Main Camera

Here's the Inspector of my Main Camera (**Perspective Projection**):
[image]

##### Orthographic Camera

Inspector of one of the orthographic cameras:
[image]

##### UI Camera

Inspector of the UI camera (also orthographic):
[image]

###### Canvas Details

Inspector of the canvas I'm using for the UI:
[image]

I'm trying to make a sort of switch for different orthogonal projections, that makes use of different cameras to change the perspective.
Therefore I made a dropdown UI element that seems to work fine: I used the `gameobject.SetActive(bool)` method to switch camera, even though the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/Manual/MultipleCameras.html) say to use the `enabled` property to switch cameras, because that wasn't working.

#### Switch Camera Script

```cs
public class ChangeCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Camera> cameras;

    public void SetCamera(int camera)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cameras.Count; i++)
        {
            cameras[i].gameObject.SetActive(i == camera);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Problem

So far so good.
The problem is that, when I switch the camera in **Play Mode**, the UI disappears.

#### Demo

##### 1. Perspective Camera

Before switching camera (UI correctly displayed):
[image]

##### 2. Orthographic Camera

After switching camera to orthogonal (UI disappeared):
[image]

And that's what I see in the Scene window:
[image]

### Update

Setting the Canvas "Render Mode" to `Screen Space - Overlay` seems to be solving the problem, but then I'm not able to see the 3D objects in the UI:
[image]

Comment: why not use screen space overlay for the UI?

Comment: and your orthographic camera should probably have the same clear flags as your perspective one in general ... then try to set the UI camera depth higher ... your perspective camera has `-1`, your orthographic one `0` which is the same as your UI camera ... so whichever comes latest in the hierarchy will probably render on top

Comment: Sound like the near plane on your camera is clipping the canvas. Change 'Plane distance' on the UI object until your canvas becomes visible.

Comment: @derHugo Seems like that would solve my problem, but if I set the Render Mode to `Screen Space - Overlay` I'm not able to see the 3D objects in the UI anymore (see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAux7.png))

Comment: @derHugo changing the depth solved it :)

Comment: Using the screen space overlay you wouldn't need a dedicated cera for this at all. You would just render and handle it through the other camera

Comment: @derHugo to me it seems a bit more difficult to implement it this way, because the 3D elements have to be children of a ScrollView, which is a UI element... but I'm still noob with Unity and you definitely know more than me, so I'll try looking it up. Thank you for the advice

Comment: Ah I see, didn't focus on the 3d items, you are probably right then those would still have to be rendered by a dedicated camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was easier than I thought. Big thanks to [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) :)

#### Problem

The problem here is the [camera depth](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-depth.html):

- the Main Camera (perspective) has a depth of `-1`;
- the UI camera has a depth of `0`;
- the orthographic cameras have a depth of `0`.

Since the camera depth controls the cameras rendering order, a camera with a lower depth gets rendered before with a camera with higher depth. Therefore, when I was changing the camera to one of the orthographics one, they were rendered in the same depth of the UI, masking it completely.

#### Solution

I changed the orthographic cameras depth to `-1` (the same as the Main Camera), and that solved the problem.
NB: this had nothing to do with the camera using perspective or orthographic projection.

#### Demo

##### 1. Before

[image]

##### 2. After

[image]